# Как передать string в textbox?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток! Имеется POST запрос, в котором есть
username=" + username + "
password = " + password + "

Так же я задал
string user = "";
string pass = "";

При открытии формы, у меня есть два текстбокса, в которые нужно ввести логин пароль и отправить на сервер по моему POST запросу. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы сначала я вводил данные в текстбокс, и они уже подставлялись в мой POST запрос ? У меня происходит отправка пустых значений.

Comment: код Вашей формы, пожалуйста, приведите в пример.

Comment: сделайте кнопку "отправить" или "ок" или придумайте как ее назвать и по клику по ней отправляйте данные

Comment: Уже разобрался, всего то надо было string user = textbox1.text;